# Как зашифровать строки из .txt-файла?

Tags: bash, cmd, шифрование, хеширование, sha

Задача стоит с помощью bash на Windows захешировать (SHA256) содержимое .txt-файла.
Есть соль: abc123

То есть, имеется файл:

> строка1
>   строка2
>   строка3

Создаётся некий цикл, который *каждую строчку* шифрует и записывает результат в новый .txt-файл.

На выходе получаем

> 7fsa89f7s
>   s9d8af7sa 
>   sadf9879s

Это и есть hash тех строк, которые были изначально.

Comment: из вопроса (слишком глобального) своершенно не ясно, с чем именно у вас возникли трудности. для уточнения текста вопроса нажмите [edit]

Comment: структура цикла - как его написать, не понятно.

Comment: ну вы б хоть одним глазком в документацию заглянули бы. `cat первый.файл | while read line; do echo $line; done > другой.файл`

Comment: это на php написано. я через bash хочу сделать

Comment: Это он на баше)

Comment: И хеш - это не шифрование

Comment: @eri, шифрование в одну сторону :-)

Comment: я помню ктото изобретал архиватор на основе хеша)

Comment: bash на Windows? Может, все-таки, bat?

Comment: @pincher1519, тогда уж -- *кодирование*. Кстати, обладая секретной кодовой книгой (ну, очень длинной) стороны могут даже обмениваться такими посланиями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу использовать Powershell.

Возьмем [этот](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-StringHash-aa843f71) скрипт для хеширования строки.

```
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography;
using namespace System.Text;

Function Get-StringHash([String] $String, $HashName = "SHA256")
{
    $StringBuilder = New-Object StringBuilder
    [HashAlgorithm]::Create($HashName).ComputeHash([Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($String)) | % {
        [Void]$StringBuilder.Append($_.ToString("x2"))
    }
    $StringBuilder.ToString()
}

$salt = "abc123"
$in = Get-Content "C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\in.txt"

foreach ($s in $in.Split(' '))
{
    $salted = $s + $salt
    Get-StringHash($salted) | Out-File -append "C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\out.txt"
}
```

Данные берутся из файла in.txt и помещаются в out.txt.

Длина хеша SHA256 - как и указано в его названии - 256 бит (32 байта). Поэтому непонятно, откуда вы получили такие короткие строки.

Comment: вижу название файла, например, "in.txt" , но не вижу путь к нему

Comment: произошла ошибка при вызове метода, т.к. [System.Object[]] не содержит метод с именем "Split". строка:1 знак:25.

Comment: посолить - это сделать конкатенацию (+), то есть прибавить строку, как это корректно сделать в данном примере? ничего похожего не делал до этого.

Comment: @DmitryNikitin - Путь указывается традиционно, как в любом другом языке. \ Командлет Get-Content возвращает строку. Где вы взяли массив объектов - я без понятия. Просто скопируйте код. \ Добавил соль. Обновил ответ.